# Is it possible to modify parameters of UploadPortletRequest?

Tags: upload, struts, liferay

Is it possible to modify parameters of `uploadPortletRequest`?

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = 
                            PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequestNew);
```

I need to modify `uploadPortletRequest` parameters as:

```
uploadPortletRequest.setParameter("key","value")
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: i don;t think so we can set parameter but we can use uploadPortletRequest.setAttribute("key","value")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is nothing like `setParameter`. Infact no request instance like `HttpServletRequest` or `PortletRequest` or `RenderRequest` etc has such method. Its not part of the specification.

There is a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319638/httpservletrequest-setparameter) about this.

So you only have `uploadPortletRequest.setAttribute(key, value)`, which is more than enough for all the requirements.

Also what would be the need to do this, if you can elaborate I am sure SO users can help you.

Hope this helps.