# Passing a very long URL to a HTTPServletRequest

Tags: java, jsp, httprequest

I want to pass a long series of request parameters (over 2000 characters in total) from one .jsp to another (via a URL), and make it seem to the receiving `HTTPServletRequest` as if it received the request parameters normally.

I cannot simply pass the URL normally as IE11 is truncating the URL at about 2000 characters (see [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) so I need to have some kind of workaround.

It is trivial to save the url in the ClientSession with a key in one .jsp

```
public String addValue(String aString) {
    String key=""+UUID.randomUUID();
    mapValues.put(key, aString);
    return key;
}
```

and then retrieve it in the other .jsp

```
public String getValue(String key) {
        return mapValues.get(key);
}
```

However the other .jsp needs a HTTPServletRequest and not a string

I.e. I need to be able to do

```
public MyPosition(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.id= (String)request.getParameter("ID");
```

Is there anyway of doing this by converting the retrieved url to a HTTPServletRequest?

I know that I could rewrite `MyPosition` to take a string and extract the data from there directly, but I would much rather not touch the very lengthy, legacy code.

If I could do `setParameter` on the request, then this would be a solution. But such an option is not available (see [HttpServletRequest - SetParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319638/httpservletrequest-setparameter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

Comment: Are you passing the values from *.jsp to another *.jsp? Or to a servlet?

Comment: From one .jsp to another .jsp

Comment: You want to pass the request which comes to the 1.jsp to 2.jsp by adding some more parameters.. right?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala: that is definitely one possible direction of solving the problem, but it is not necessarily the only direction... Thanks!

Comment: what about storing the url somewhere and then giving that a unique identifier... then use the unique identifier to retrieve the url you assigned to it? (sending the unique identifier in the url instead of the whole url)

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte that is exactly what I am doing and describe above! The question is what I do with the URL after I have retrieved it. It is a `string` and I need a `HTTPServletRequest`!

Comment: my bad, missed that part. I don't understand why you can't just save the url as a session attribute? Why do you need `HTTPServletRequest` ?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte. I am trying to solve the problem without adapting my old existing legacy code. If I have to, then I will! I attempted to explain this above in the penultimate paragraph... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both @dimplex's and @Deadron's solutions, which I think should both work, but didn't manage to implement either in the short time frame I had available.

I ended up replacing the `HTTPServletRequest request` parameter in the `MyPosition` function with `String urlKey` and adding the following line inside the function

```
RequestStr request=new RequestStr(cSession,urlKey);
```

now my existing code did not need to be changed at all, and `request.getParameter("paramName")` would call my function below.

```
public class RequestStr {
    String url = "";

    public RequestStr(ClientSession cSession, String urlKey) {
        super();
        this.url = cSession.getValue(urlKey);
    }

    public String getParameter(String aParam) {
        int i = url.indexOf("?" + aParam + "=");
        if (i == -1) {
            i = url.indexOf("&" + aParam + "=");
        }
        if (i == -1) {
            return null;
        } else {

            int j = url.indexOf("&", i + 1);
            if (j == -1) {
                return url.substring(i + aParam.length() + 2);
            } else {
                return url.substring(i + aParam.length() + 2, j);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So all I needed to do was to save the very long URL in the session in a map with key `urlKey` and then in the request just passed this `urlKey`, and then I could retrieve the long URL via the `urlKey` and then decode it via my `RequestStr` class

Comment: You need to make sure you call URLDecoder.decode on the query string params or you may have strings containing percent encoded values.  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Answer (score 1):

The only way to modify an HttpServletRequest is to [wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make a standard POST request instead of what sounds like a GET request.

Comment: In what way would this help? Would it bypass the 2000 character limitation?

Comment: Post bodies are not subjected to url length restrictions. You can pass a body of arbitrary length